# error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('bdist-egg')

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to install matplotlib using the following command and running into below error,can anyone provide inputs what is wrong here and how to overcome this?

```
 easy_install matplotlib
```

ERROR:-

```
Couldn't find index page for 'bdist_egg' (maybe misspelled?)
Couldn't find index page for 'bdist_egg' (maybe misspelled?)
Couldn't find index page for 'bdist_egg' (maybe misspelled?)
Couldn't find index page for 'bdist_egg' (maybe misspelled?)
No local packages or download links found for bdist-egg
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('bdist-egg')
No local packages or download links found for bdist-egg
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('bdist-egg')
```

Comment: We need your OS version and your python version.

Comment: @btoueg - windows7 enterprise,python 2.7.3

Comment: Have you tried installing with `pip`?

Comment: @btoueg - am trying to install on windows..pip is for linux,right?

Comment: `pip` is a python module for python package management. Its purpose is to provide an alternative to `easy_install`: it's better and its usage is widely spread.

Comment: `pip` is great but one thing it can't do is install packages via Windows binaries.  You still have to use `easy_install` for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to build matplotlib yourself on Windows. Just use their provided binaries at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/downloads

Comment: This doesn't work if one is trying to install to a virtual environment on windows

Answer (score 0):

As VooDooNOFX said, it's easiest to use a pre-built executable on Windows.  [This UIC repository of Windows executables](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) is very helpful when you run across a library that needs to be compiled for Windows.  This also has more recent versions than some other sources - at the time of this writing the github page for matplotlib is at 1.2.0 while the UIC repository has 1.3.1.

If you only have one version of python installed just double clicking the executable will work to install the package.  If you need to install into a [virtual environment](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), activate your environment and use the following to install the package:

```
easy_install mypackage.exe
```

I found this question because I was getting the same output as you even when following these suggestions.  If you still see those errors, it may be that the package installed correctly** but easy_install is trying to download and install the package again.

If you explicitly tell easy_install to not automatically download and install other packages this problem goes away.  You can do that with the `-N` [command line option](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#command-line-options).

** You can test that by typing `python -c 'import matplotlib'`.  A good installation will not produce any errors.